# What're the minimum components that must be included in a runtime Java 8.0_72 deployment sufficient only to run a text-only HelloWorld.class?

Tags: java

**Target environment:**

- Windows 7 (6.1)
- JRE 1.8.0_72 64bit

`HelloWorld.class` compiled with 1.8.0_72 64bit JDK from:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Made an empty folder on my desktop.
Copied C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe to the empty folder.
Copied HelloWorld.class from where I'd compiled it.
Started a new cmd with its current directory set to the new folder.
Typed in the following to get rid of all environment variables:
`for /f "delims==" %a in ('set') do set %a=`
Checked to make sure they were all gone:
`set`
Which produced output like this:
[image]

Which shows there isn't any classpath or path or other environment variable set now.
So now I type the following, and see the (expected result):
[image]
That's pretty neat, because that's only 1K for the .class file and 203K for java.exe.
Can it really be that easy?

Nah. I think I'm going to try another tack. I must be getting java.dll and .jar files via the Windows registry.

In my reading I discovered that the jre embedded in the JDK does NOT contain any registry references.  I'm going to copy the jre from an installation on one of my computers to a flash drive, along with the HelloWorld.class file. The result on the flash drive looks like this:

[image: just a stock jre from the jdk and HelloWorld.class]

Then I'm going to try running HelloWorld on a computer having NO Java installed at all. And here's what the result of that looked like:

[image: It worked!]

That's pretty cool. No registry complaints, no installed Java, and yet it ran fine! Still, it's 186 MB.

I think the next step is to start removing stuff and see how far I can go before it no longer works.

To start with, I'm going to remove everything except java.exe, but I'm going to leave the directory structure alone.

Well that's interesting:

[image: it didn't find java.dll AND it expected a directory entry]

I guess it does check the registry after all. I think I should put java.dll back and try again. So here's what's in jre\bin on the flash drive now:

[image: just java.exe and java.dll]

And here's the result:

[image: Error: could not open 'D:\jre\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg']

So I at least need that file too. Interestingly, that's the only thing in the amd64 directory anyway:

[image: jvm.cfg]

And this gives us the next step ...

[image: Error: missing 'server' JVM at 'D:\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll']

Okay, so just add that as well. Well, it wanted jre\bin\verify.dll.

And then that wanted jre\bin\zip.dll.

Now, that needed java/lang/Object, so I guess we need jre\lib\rt.jar

And guess, what? That was enough:

[image]

So the total jre minimal footprint was: 69.1 MB (72,519,711 bytes)

Compare that with the jre total footprint: 186 MB (195,043,328 bytes)

Hardly seems worth the effort.  Next time, I'm just going to use the jre from the jdk with everything in it.

Comment: Without `rt.jar`? You should be getting a missing class definition on `java.lang.String`

Comment: I know. Kinda surprised me too. Could I be getting one via a registry entry or something? <br>

Comment: Final note. I think I know why java wanted server\java.dll.  It is mentioned in the jvm.cfg: -server KNOWN

Comment: and -client IGNORE